# How to get the SQL of a View using GetSchema in AS400

Tags: c#, database, db2, schema, ibm-midrange

I am trying to get the SQL using `GetSchema` but the `View_Definition` column is not retrieved.

This is my function to retrieve the view information:

```
internal DataTable GetViewDefinition(AS400Library library, string viewName)
{
    var connection = ODBC.Instance.GetConnection(library);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return connection.GetSchema("Views", new string[] { library.ToString(), null, viewName });
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

`GetViewDefinition` is returning the following columns but not the `view_definition`:

1. TABLE_CAT
2. TABLE_SCHEM
3. TABLE_NAME
4. TABLE_TYPE
5. REMARKS

How can I get the SQL itself?

Comment: By using `GetSchema` of what? That is, what exact driver are you using? And what OS version is on your "AS400"?

Comment: Where [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668760(v=vs.110).aspx) you see that `GetSchema()` is supposed to return "view_definition"?

Comment: @mustaccio I wondered that, too, but it wasn't clear if any DB2 for i driver specifically provided GetSchema() or if the DB2 UDB driver was being used instead, which apparently doesn't support "view_definition" (unless undocumented or PTFed or something). I couldn't find it in any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ODBC and ADO.NET are generic interfaces, they only support the "least common denominator" of features and are unaware of implementation-specific details.

You can find view definitions in the System i [catalog views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm), `QSYS2.VIEWS` or `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`. Check the manual for your version, as names may be different; `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is only supported since 6.1, I believe.

Comment: Your link helped me to find VIEW_DEFINITION https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcatsysviews.htm